# Error: Not implemented: HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext (without installing the canvas npm package) in FabricJs

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, fabricjs

I use fabric.js in my project and I got this error `Error: Not implemented: HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext (without installing the canvas npm package)` when I build my project. Please help me, how to resolve it.

**my package.json**

```
{
    "name": "my-project",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "nuxt",
        "build": "nuxt build",
        "start": "nuxt start",
        "generate": "nuxt generate",
        "test": "jest"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "fabric": "^4.2.0",
        "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
        "nuxt": "^2.13.3",
        "nuxt-i18n": "^6.13.8",
        "sqlite3": "^5.0.0",
        "vue-axios": "^2.1.5",
   },
   "devDependencies": {
        "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.3",
        "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
        "babel-jest": "^26.0.1",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.11.0",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
        "jest": "^26.0.1",
        "prettier": "^2.0.5",
        "vue-jest": "^3.0.4"
   }
}
```

Comment: Could you add some sample code that throws that error?  With which browser are you running into this issue?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by the documentation, FabricJS depends on [node-canvas](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas) to implement HTML Canvas element.

Depending on the OS that you're running, you will need to run different commands as indicated in the node-canvas documentation.